# Set up 301 status code with <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0, url=xxx"/>

Tags: web, redirect

Set Status Code = 301, We want to set status code for redirect url.

Comment: Questions of this brevity are nearly always regarded as off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please expand (greatly) on your question.

Comment: Thanks, But i have a old website with url - http://www.example.com, but when i deployed new website with same domain name but in subdirectory related to language. New url - http://www.example.com/en , so i want to be when i hit old url it should be redirect to new url. I have used the web.config setting, but its working for non-www to www only, not for www to www with sub folder. Please suggest. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `<meta>` tags for redirection; that hurts your SEO. A 301 redirect essentially means "Moved Permanently" as an HTTP status code and will be recognized for SEO purposes.

If you are using an Apache server, put in rules of redirecting to your new files in the `.htaccess` file, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /oldfolder/file1.html /newfolder/file1.html
Redirect 301 /oldfolder/file2.html /newfolder/file2.html
```

Or, if all the files reside in one folder, you could use a `RewriteRule` similar to below that's a lot quicker to test and implement:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$ /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If your website is on an IIS server, you need to edit your `Web.config` file and add something like this into it. For this example, the first rule is for redirecting non-WWW browser searches of the URL to the actual WWW-version of the website, and the second rule is for redirecting from an old URL to a new URL.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Non-WWW to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
              </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="oldToNewURL" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="http://example.com" />
              </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/en/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't know if you are trying to redirect from one domain to another or if you are trying to migrate files to a new directory. You need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: This looks like a lot of effort that would have been better expended on a good question. The question will almost certainly be closed as off-topic, which in turn may cause the question author to repost elsewhere. In circumstances such as these, it is better if you can just encourage the question author to clarify their question.

Comment: Thanks Max, But i have a old website with old url - http://www.example.com, but when i deployed new website with same domain name but in subdirectory related to language. New url - http://www.example.com/en , so i want to be when i hit old url it should be redirect to new url. I have used the web.config setting, but its working for non-www to www only, not for www to www with sub folder. Please suggest. Thanks,

Comment: @gazanafaralam See my edit and see the extra rule I added.

Comment: Hi @MaxVoisard, i used your suggestion, but not able to achieve the goal. below is my requirement. all these URL should be redirect to below New url [link](https://www.example.ae
https://www.example.ae/
https://www.example.ae/en/
https://www.example.ae/en
https://example.ae
https://example.ae/
https://example.ae/en/
https://example.ae/en
http://example.ae
http://example.ae/
http://example.ae/en/
http://example.ae/en
http://www.example.ae
http://www.example.ae/
http://www.example.ae/en/
http://www.example.ae/en) New URL: (https://www.example.ae/en/) . Please help

Comment: Please Open all these old URL in notepad and see the New Url also

Comment: @gazanafaralam First off, you provided 16 old URLs when there's really only 2 different URLs (example.ae and example.ae/en). Second off, why would I want to open these in Notepad?

Comment: Hi @MaxVoisard, There is 16 different urls but i need to be redirect to one seo url only (https://www.example.ae/en/). Please provide the web.config configuration.